# Как проверить расширение файла?

Tags: java, файлы

Есть метод, который проходит по папкам и подпапкам.

Если он встречает папку, то закидывает её в очередь, а если файл, то должен проверить его расширение, и если оно совпадает с введённым – вывести имя файла.

Но он у меня не работает. Я только учусь.

P.S.
Кусок с фильтром взял из интернета.

```
 public static void walker(File rootPapka) {

    ArrayList<File> allFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayDeque<File> papky = new ArrayDeque<File>();

    papky.add(rootPapka);

    while (papky.peek() != null) {

        File[] open = papky.getFirst().listFiles();

        for (File entry : open) {
            if (entry.isDirectory()) {

                papky.add(entry);

            } else {

                String[] files = entry.list(new FilenameFilter() {

                    @Override public boolean accept(File folder, String name) {
                        return name.endsWith(".txt");
                    }

                });

                for ( String fileName : files ) {
                    System.out.println("File: " + fileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Разрешение от расширения отличаешь?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то вам нужно вывести имена всех файлов в дереве каталогов.
Для этого существуют удобные методы:

1) walkFileTree c созданием FileVisitor:

```
Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get("C:/folder"), new FileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                if(file.getFileName().endsWith(".txt")) System.out.println("File: " + file.getFileName());
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
```

2) walk с созданием Stream:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("C:/folder"), FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS).forEach(file -> {
            if (!file.toFile().isDirectory() && if(file.getFileName().endsWith(".txt"))) System.out.println(file.getFileName());
        });
```